# Sending Akka.net cluster gossip to Azure worker role console

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, akka.net, akka.net-cluster

I'm developing an Azure cloud service including multiple worker roles that form an akka.net cluster. How do I accomplish getting the cluster gossip and other messages end up in the compute emulator console windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment I'm working on an Akka.NET cluster that will be hosted as Azure Cloud Services and ran into the same problem.

The quickest way I found to accomplish this is to write a logging adapter (though I' still relatively new to Akka.NET, so take this advice with a pinch of salt). Here's the basic one I'm using for now:

```
public class ComputeEmulatorConsoleLogger : ReceiveActor
{
    public ComputeEmulatorConsoleLogger()
    {
        Receive<InitializeLogger>(_ =>
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Compute emulator console logger started.");
            Sender.Tell(new LoggerInitialized());
        });

        Receive<LogEvent>(ev =>
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(ev.ToString());
        });
    }
}
```

And in the `akka` HOCON configuration section add the class' path and assembly name, for example:

```
loggers = [ "WorkerRole2.ComputeEmulatorConsoleLogger,WorkerRole2" ]
```

It's not perfect, but as you can see it works well enough so you're not pulling your hair out wondering what the actor system is up to:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Landrew Glad to help! Also, I noticed that your original question was tagged as `akka` (instead of `akka.net`) which means it probably won't get the exposure you were hoping with the community. I only stumbled across it because I'm subscribed to the `akka.net-cluster` tag!

Comment: Right, I'll have the tag fixed.

Comment: Thanks for this, worked like a treat for me too. One question if I may - have you used the endpoint configuration in Azure to setup Akka.Remote? I have a simple project with one Web Role and one Worker Role, and would like to use the Endpoint config to setup the appropriate network setup for web to converse with Akka on the worker role, and I'm guessing you may have already done this which will save me some time if you could share any findings. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, yes I have managed to setup the cloud service cluster and it was probably one of the most frustrating experiences I've had recently, between [problems that existed in Akka.Cluster](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34145111/1138552), and Microsoft's use of the ancient .NET 4.5.0 as the default framework (requiring a worker role startup task to install a newer version every time I add a new node to the cluster - painfully slow). Regarding the network setup, I can give you a few tips from what I found (cont)

Comment: Since the instances are firewalled, one can't  just have the nodes in the cluster pick a random port when connecting to the seeds (at least in the way I have my cluster setup, with nodes living in geographically separate regions). If each node is a separate cloud service with its own worker/web role, bot the seed nodes and the remaining "slave" nodes need to have a fixed "Input" TCP endpoint that will allow traffic from outside. (cont)

Comment: If they are configured as a single cloud service but with multiple worker/web roles in the same service then the "Internal" TCP input endpoint configuration should suffice if you don't require that they be reachable from outside the datacenter. This is what I managed to figure out with Akka.Cluster, but using plain old Akka.Remote should work pretty much the same. @Morgan Skinner hope this helps and let me know if I can clarify anything else!

Comment: @easuter - I'm still in need of some help on this. What do I set in my hocon so that the client can connect to the server? Normally I'd define the path to the remote machine such as this - "akka.tcp://TransferServer@127.0.0.1:9090", however this has the node address for localhost in it. What do I replace this with so that a web role can talk to akka.net hosted in a worker role? Thanks!

Comment: @MorganSkinner, yeah sorry I forgot about that part, it also needs some elbow grease. In the HOCON `remote` section, you must set the `hostname` field to `0.0.0.0` so that the actorsystem listens on any available interface, and not only on loopback. In this same section, also set the `public-hostname` field to the host name that Azure attributes to the cloud service (eg: `your-service-name.cloudapp.net`). Nodes should communicate using this public address, and not fixed IPs (unless you configure fixed public IPs for them, but IIRC Azure gives you 5 for free, and the rest you must pay for).

Comment: @MorganSkinner if you still have trouble after this perhaps we can continue talking via a StackOverflow chat session or something like that, and I can provide more detailed info (would rather not here since the project is proprietary).

Comment: easuter @MorganSkinner ... thanks for explaining all that ! It is clear that setting up an akka.net cluster on Azure is not documented anywhere. It would be great to have a blog about that, perhaps with some sample code.
thanks